# iOS table navcontroller not working

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

self.searchBar.delegate=self;
self.searchResultTable.delegate=self;
self.searchResultTable.dataSource=self;
[self.searchResultTable setHidden:YES];

}
```

In my cells I insert text and when I click on cell I need go to another table but this not work:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

TableViewController *tvc=[[TableViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tvc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: please describe you views, is it in same navigationBarController or it's modal view

Comment: you hooked views up in storyboard?

Comment: modal view with search bar

Comment: if i use [self presentModalViewController:tvc animated:YES]; i go to next view and back automatically

Comment: if you want to present modal view you don't need pushViewController method you need to use  presentModalViewController: method

Comment: check this tutorial if you use modal - http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/08/15/iphone-development-tutorial-present-modal-view/ or this if you want to push view http://www.cimgf.com/2009/06/25/uitabbarcontroller-with-uinavigationcontroller-using-interface-builder/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are doing something like this to present this controller:

```
SearchViewController *searchViewController = [SearchViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:searchViewController animated:YES];
```

then your view controller doesn't have a navigation controller

You need to change it to

```
SearchViewController *searchViewController = [SearchViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:searchViewController];
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

then `[self.navigationController pushViewController:tvc animated:YES];` will work